# Livewire ignore does not receive correct data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js for dropdown styling with livewire. I'm using livewire for a data table with sortable columns and pagination. The issue is, every time I make pagination or a sort by column, the javascript goes missing thus, there's no styling for the dropdown. I've solved the styling issue using `wire:ignore`. Now the new problem that I have is that the data passed to the dropdown is not accurate.

```
@foreach($applications as $application)
    <p>{{$application->status}}</p>
    <div wire:ignore>
        <select class="selectize" name="status" data-width="200px">
            @foreach(['Pending',
                      'Hired',
                      'Under consideration'] as $status)
                <option
                    @if($application->status === $status) selected @endif>{{ $status }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Inside the `<p>{{$application->status}}</p>` tag, I get the status 'Pending' but on the dropdown, it shows 'Hired'. The correct status is 'Pending'.

Comment: Have you tried `wire:model="status"` ? By doing so, your `@if selected @endif` should not even be necessary. But you will need `value="{{ $status }}"` though

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I dont get it. The main reason is that, inside the if statement, im not getting the correct $application->status. If i remove the wire:ignore, I get the correct one.

Comment: `<select wire:model="status" ....>` will bind `$status` to your `select` tag. Then livewire will automatically select the value and update `$status` when the input is changed. And you don't have to remove `wire:ignore`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I did that and I get gibbersish, status is an array, so it wouldnt even know which one to select without the application status

Comment: `wire:model="application.status"` sorry

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier still the same, the application status is not correct inside the wire:ignore. Inside the div and outside the div gives different status

Comment: Doesn't this works for you ? https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/11bb105a-d1ad-4fad-a997-cc1c27ad5bb7 if this works without selectize and doesn't with selectize, it means you have to listen for changes on the input and update selectize value.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier my bad, I think u misunderstood. I'm getting the application data from the livewire controller inside a for loop. Check the updated code. thanks

Comment: So... this ? https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/7eb3cda9-b079-41e3-bfd2-9773af8b6370

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier your solution works but if u add pagination, it doesnt work. Check this out https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/91af861b-d482-4f8f-a426-2a6e37b94a16 thanks

Comment: how you initialize the selectize.js??? in blade script? could you share this part? I know about some issues using js elements with Livewire and not always works well, but with some cases I use a kind of hydrates call

Comment: @Prospero I'm initalizing it inside a JS file and call it in the blade. but how do u call the script inside hydrate() ?

Answer (score 0):

(from comment) @stalwart1014 for example, when I use "select2" I do this
in content section

```
<select id="select2" wire:model="some">
//.....
</select>
```

in script section

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.initSelectDrop=()=>{
      $('#select2').select2({
          placeholder: '{{ __('Select') }}',
          allowClear: true});
      }
   initSelectDrop();
   window.livewire.on('select2',()=>{
      initSelectDrop();
   });
});
```

and in component

```
public function hydrate()
{
   $this->emit('select2');
}
```

This not always function properly with JS element...but hope this can help you. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

it's maybe a bit late, but worth to mention for the future, I will do not point directly to your issue but explain the workaround of `wire:ignore`, the `wire:ignore` directive ignores the updates or changes for the further requests and updates, this attributes is defined for playing with JS third party library, the `wire:ignore` directive prevent all it's nested elements from updating if you wish to except Childs from updating you can use `wire:ignore.self` directive